# Ef core not tracking changes for child collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have these models

```
public class WarehouseAllocation
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Warehouse Warehouse { get; set; }
   public IList<Dispatch> Dispatches { get; set; }
   //---- removed other properties for brevity
}

public class Dispatch 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public IList<DispatchDetail> DispatchDetails { get; set; }
   //---- removed other properties for brevity
}
```

On the database,

Dispatch has a **foreign key** **WarehouseAllocationId** that refers WarehouseAllocation table.

I used Fluent API to map the model to the database as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<WarehouseAllocation>(m =>
{
    m.ToTable("WarehouseAllocation");

    m.Property(wa => wa.Id).HasColumnName("WarehouseAllocationId")
         .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    m.HasKey(wa => wa.Id);

    m.HasOne(wa => wa.Warehouse)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("WarehouseId");

    m.HasMany(w => w.Dispatches)
        .WithOne();
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Dispatch>(m =>
{
    m.ToTable("Dispatch");

    m.Property(wa => wa.Id).HasColumnName("DispatchId")
         .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    m.HasKey(wa => wa.Id);
});
```

When I call
`dbContext.WarehouseAllocations .Include(w => w.Dispatches) .ThenInclude(w => w.DispatchDetails).ToList()`,
Ef core retrieves all the warehouse allocations with their dispatches including the details.

The problem is when I use this method:

```
var warehouseAllocation = dbContext.WarehouseAllocations
    .Include(w => w.Dispatches)
    .ThenInclude(d => d.DispatchDetails)
    .SingleOrDefault(w => w.Id == warehouseAllocationId);

warehouseAllocation.Dispatches.Add(new Dispatch
{
   //--including other properties
   DispatchDetails = new List<DispatchDetail> {
       new DispatchDetail
       {
          //--other properties
       }
   }
});

// call another query that includes WarehouseAllocation

dbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges() // this is false

dbContext.SaveChanges() // this keeps returning zero
```

Why is the change is not being detected?

**UPDATED:**

After I make the changes and before calling SaveChanges(), for the sake of business Events, I call a LINQ query that includes the warehouse allocation. Does Ef core overwrite the current entity state?

Comment: Did you tried `dbContext.Dispatches.Add(new Dispatch...)`?

Comment: @Fabio No.. because how do I put the warehouseAllocationId given the above model?

Comment: `dbContext.Dispatches.Add(new Dispatch { WarehouseAllocationId = warehouseAllocationId , ...})` ?

Comment: EF Core has the concept of 'convention over configuration' Your Fluent API is almost completely re-stating the defaults of EF Core's conventions. Let it do the work for you.  (The only major difference is EF Core will pluralize your tables without explicitly telling you not to)

Comment: The code you have provided in the original post will not compile due to the following:: in your `Dispatch` model you have `public IList<DispatchDetail> DispatchDetails { get; set; }`  and in your calling code you have `.ThenInclude(d => d.DispatchDetail)`  which should be `d.DispatchDetails` If your code does indeed compile I would recommend updating the code in the post, you may have inadvertently missed something else.

Comment: @AdamVincent sorry it was typo

Comment: It's courtesy that if your original answer is answered, and you have a new question to mark it as solved and ask a new question, instead of changing the question as you progress through your problems and solutions.

Comment: If you make a tracking query, make some changes, and make the same tracking query again, in the same context. I can't say exactly how EF will behave, but I wouldn't even try.

Comment: your second query could be `AsNoTracking()` will little effect, but if you're trying to Query->Make Changes-> Query->Make Chages->Save in the same context, I would consider splitting them into 2 contexts, or use the `Unit of Work` pattern.

Comment: @AdamVincent I did use Unit of Work... all the code structure that u have seen is to make my question as short as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I was making another query that includes the warehouse allocation, all this before calling SaveChanges().

i.e.

```
var shipment = _myDbContext.Shipments
                .Include(s => s.WarehouseAllocations)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.Dispatches)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.DispatchDetails)
                .Include(s => s.WarehouseAllocations)
                .SingleOrDefault(s => s.WarehouseAllocations.Select(w => w.Id).Contains(warheouseAllocationId));
```

and I do some business event logic on the Shipment and save all changes. (NOW I CAN DO IT IN A BETTER WAY)

I'm guessing, Ef overwrites the entity states if you make a query that includes the affected entity type before saving ur changes.

Answer (score -1):

If you change:

```
 var warehouseAllocation = dbContext.WarehouseAllocations
 .Include(w => w.Dispatches)
 .SingleOrDefault(w => w.Id == warehouseAllocationId);
```

To:

```
 var warehouseAllocation = dbContext.WarehouseAllocations
 .Include(w => w.Dispatches)
 .ThenInclude(d => d.DispatchDetail)
 .SingleOrDefault(w => w.Id == warehouseAllocationId);
```

It should inform EF that you wish to include DispatchDetail into its change tracker.  This will also pull all of the `DispatchDetail` values for w from the DB.

Comment: *It should inform EF that you wish to include DispatchDetail into its change tracker* -- That's not what `Include` is for.

Comment: Won't compile, model is `public IList<DispatchDetail> DispatchDetails { get; set; }`